# How to delete/remove certificates from Mono certificate stores My and Trust?

Tags: linux, ssl, mono

I have  added the certificate to the Mono 3.2.8 store by using the following command in Linux.

```
    certmgr -add -c -m My mycert.cer
```

The added cert can be viewed by

```
    certmgr -list -c -m My mycert.cer
```

Used the following command to delete the previously added certificate. But the certificate is not getting deleted. The command didn't give any error messgae.

```
    certmgr -del -c -m My mycert.cer
```

1. How to remove the certificate from the stores (My,CA,Trust etc ?)
2. Where is Mono storing the certificate details in the system?

I tried to add the certificate by using the command mozroots, but by default it's trying to add the certificate to the store AddressBook. (I couldn't find any command to remove the certificate from the store My or Trust)

```
    mozroots --import --machine --sync
    certmgr -ssl -m https://test:1200/service
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> 1. How to remove the certificate from the stores (My,CA,Trust etc)?

Running this command:

```
certmgr -del -c -v -m Trust CERTHASH
```

Where CERTHASH is the number in `Unique Hash` (you can extract this value running `certmgr -list -c -v -m YOURSTORE`, see example at the end of my answer):

> 2. Where is Mono storing the certificate details in the system?

In some of these paths:

```
/usr/share/.mono/certs/
~/.config/.mono/certs/
```

Examples:

Add new certificate to `Trust` store (valid stores are: `My`, `AddressBook`, `CA`, `Trust` and `Disallowed`):

```
me@myserver:~$ certmgr -add -c -v -m Trust google.cer 
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.6.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
```

List certificates:

```
me@myserver:~$ certmgr -list -c -v -m Trust
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.6.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

X.509 v3 Certificate
  Serial Number: 7CBE60802548D325
  Issuer Name:   C=US, O=Google Inc, CN=Google Internet Authority G2
  Subject Name:  C=US, S=California, L=Mountain View, O=Google Inc, CN=*.google.com
  Valid From:    10/09/2014 14:03:47
  Valid Until:   09/12/2014 0:00:00
  Unique Hash:   4D348D0E4028C850A7C783413571111E8E3BD9DE
  Key Algorithm:        1.2.840.113549.1.1.1
  Algorithm Parameters: 0500
  Public Key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
  Signature Algorithm:  1.2.840.113549.1.1.5
  Algorithm Parameters: 0500
  Signature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
  Private Key:          False
  KeyPair Key:          False
```

Remove certificate:

```
me@myserver:~$ certmgr -del -c -v -m Trust 4D348D0E4028C850A7C783413571111E8E3BD9DE
```