# Mono WCF app can't find X509 certificates in stores on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, wcf, mono, x509

I'm working on a WCF application that must make calls to a web-service. The program works fine when testing with http. When https is used, I'm getting the exception "Specified X509 certificate with find type ... was not found in X509 store ....". The program works fine with https when run on Windows and .Net, but throws the exception when run in a Linux/Mono setup. I have added the certificates on the Linux system using the certmgr.exe utility, and can list them using that same utility, so they seem to be saved in the stores ok. The application gets its configuration info from its app.config file. I've attempted to find the certificate using various different x509FindTypes and findValues (FindBySubjectName, FindBySerialNumber, FindByThumbprint), and tried adding the certificate to both the machine and personal stores, but keep getting the same exception, referencing whichever find type, location, and store I setup. The relevant part of the app.config is below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <client>
      <endpoint address="https://webserviceaddress"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="secureBasicHttpBinding"
                behaviorConfiguration="secureClientBehavior"
                contract="IWebServiceContract">
     </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="secureClientBehavior" >
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySerialNumber" findValue="AFCB6CC0417B2D459BB1F859CE070661" />         
            <serviceCertificate>
              <authentication revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </serviceCertificate>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureBasicHttpBinding"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 maxBufferSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

If anyone can offer any help on getting the certificates to be found in the stores, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete/remove certificates from Mono certificate stores My and Trust?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25918024/how-to-delete-remove-certificates-from-mono-certificate-stores-my-and-trust)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - different question though. That post regards how to properly remove certs from the stores. I have the certs added to the stores - my issue is my program isn't able to find them in any of the stores, using any of the find methods I've tried, including the hash value.